# What's the difference between these two bits of code?

Tags: java

I cannot understand why one of the following bits of code compiles and the other one doesn't.

The one that doesn't compile (Compiler says the method KeyBidings() needs a return type):

```
public KeyBidings(){
    Action rightAction = new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e){
            x+=10;
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }
    };
    Action leftAction = new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e){
            x-=10;
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }
    };

        InputMap inputMap = drawPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = drawPanel.getActionMap();

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "rightAction");
    actionMap.put("rightAction", rightAction);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "leftAction");
    actionMap.put("leftAction", leftAction);

    add(drawPanel);
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(640, 480);
    setTitle("Game");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

And the one that compiles just fine:

```
public KeyBidings(){
    Action rightAction = new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x +=10;
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }
    };

        InputMap inputMap = drawPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = drawPanel.getActionMap();

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "rightAction");
    actionMap.put("rightAction", rightAction);

    add(drawPanel);

    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

EDIT: I didn't know the difference between a constructor and a method, but now i have another problem: https://gyazo.com/cd3c21a8562589451814903febaf89fe

What's the problem here? I've included the source codes for both classes below.

Source Code 1: http://pastebin.com/vwNtJZEG
Source Code 2: http://pastebin.com/nL4SbtkM

Comment: Also be sure to read the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): methods should start with a lowercase letter. This makes it easier to differentiate between a method and a constructor (possibly copy-pasted from another class).

Comment: What is the name of the class each of these snippets are in? Are they in the same class? Is one maybe in a class called `KeyBindings` (the working one) and the other not?

Comment: @CaptainMan I edited the post and included source codes for both classes.

Comment: @Karl unfortunately I am at work and cannot for to pastebin.com links.

Comment: @KarlKuusik Don't use edits for follow-up questions. Instead, accept an answer to this question and create another one (or search for an existing one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is the constructor of a class named KeyBidings, whereas the first one is a method, with a missing return type, of some other class.

Read [the tutorial about constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Note that the compiler doesn't say that the method may not be public, as your title says. It says that it must have a return type. That's quite different.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial about constructors, but when compiling, i got the following error: https://gyazo.com/cd3c21a8562589451814903febaf89fe

What's the difference between the two codes in this case?

Comment: That's a completely different question. Read the error message. Read it again. Try to figure out what it means. Read which line it refers to. Check your code: is the class that the message refers to abstract? Does it implement ActionListener? Note that we don't know your code, so it's hard to help more. But I have the feeling that it's way too early for you to use Swing, which is quite complex. Learn the basics first, and practice with simple exercises not involving a GUI: what are classes, interfaces, methods, constructors, inner classes. This should be undestood before using Swing.

Comment: I edited the post and added links to the source codes. I know most of the basics but i'm missing a few details here and there since the tutorial on Action on oracle docs didn't help much.

Comment: Again, this is a completely different question. Accept the answer to the one you asked, and ask **another** question, with the required code and error messages, as text, in the question itself.